# How to use number as symbols in ruby

Tags: ruby

I want to use a JSON API. It has a number object, but I don't know how to use it.

The JSON looks like this:

```
"scores": {
  "2": {
    "home": "2",
    "away": "0"
   }
}
```

My Ruby code looks like this:

```
class Score < Base
  attr_accessor :2
end

def parse_scores(args = {})
  Score.new(args.fetch("scores", {}))
end
```

The same kind of code works in another class where the JSON looks like this:

```
"timer": {
    "tm": 86,
    "ts": 4,
    "tt": "1"
}
```

And the Ruby code looks like this:

```
class Timer < Base
  attr_accessor :tm, :ts, :tt       
end

def parse_timer(args = {})
  Timer.new(args.fetch("timer", {}))
end
```

The `Base` class looks like this:

```
class Base
  attr_accessor :errors

  def initialize(args = {})
    args.each do |name, value|
      attr_name = name.to_s 
      send("#{attr_name}=", value) if respond_to?("#{attr_name}=")
    end
  end
end
```

---

I find this solution (thanks everybody for help):

```
 module Betsapi
  class Score < Base
    attr_accessor :fulltime
    def initialize(args = {})
      super(args)
      self.fulltime = args['2']
   end
  end
end
```

Comment: You should have received a `SyntaxError` referring to `:2`, The correct symbol literal would be `:'2'`, but then `attr_accessor :'2'` would raise a `NameError` because it is an invalid attribute name.

Comment: How does your `Base` class look like?

Comment: @Stefan
` class Base
    attr_accessor :errors

    def initialize(args = {})
      args.each do |name, value|
        attr_name = name.to_s
        send("#{attr_name}=", value) if respond_to?("#{attr_name}=")
      end
    end
  end`

Answer (score 1):

> ```
>  attr_accessor :2
> ```

Not possible. `2` is not a valid identifier in ruby. But `tm` is.

Depending on what exactly your Score is, you may be able to do this:

```
 score['2']
```

But that's pretty much as far as you'll get without changing names.

Comment: this  score['2']  not working , i use external APi and i cant change 2 object , i must convert 2 to symbol i think

Comment: @user10337378: "i must convert 2 to symbol" - well, you can't

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: `'2'.to_sym`, `:'2'`

Comment: @JörgWMittag: and then you can't use it as an accessor name.

Comment: attr_accessor doesn't even require symbols. Works with strings just as well.

Comment: @user10337378: "this score['2'] not working" - well, you can make it work (by storing args in an internal hash field or something like that)